# Issue with <select> scroll position in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using Chrome 42.0.2311.135 m, IE 11 and Firefox 37 and I'm getting a small cosmetic issue with a `<select>` element in Chrome.

[image: Default in Chrome]

This screenshot shows the `<select>` displayed in Chrome.  I'm using jQuery to set the value of the `<select>` to the value of the first option.

[image: Default in IE11]

This screenshot shows the same page in IE11.  The problem is that Chrome is scrolling down slightly so the padding is not visible.  If I scroll to the top of the list it shows as follows.

[image: Chrome scrolled to top]

If I don't set the value of the `<select>`, Chrome displays with the top padding (i.e. the scroll bar is right at the top).

How can I select a value and have the top padding shown in Chrome?

The CSS that I'm applying to the `<select>` is quite basic.

```
.home .desktop-header form select.make, .home .desktop-header form select.model {
    width: 27%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I'm setting the value using:

`cfg.makesList.element.val(cfg.makesList.element.find("option")[0].value).change();`

A change event is hooked up to retrieve the list options for the models list.

The Makes list shows the 10 most popular options at the start of the list (and also includes them alphabetically in the full list) so the `<select>` has 10 options whose value exists twice in the list.  (see http://jsfiddle.net/0ftL6w3y/2/ for an example)

Comment: I cannot seem to recreate what you are seeing in Chrome. Could you share more information on the method you are using to select the first option?  http://jsfiddle.net/timothyjmullen/0ftL6w3y/1/

Comment: Tested @TimMullen 's fiddle, works for me on exact same Chrome version (42.0.2311.135 m).

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with the HTML produced by my page and can reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/0ftL6w3y/2/

Comment: Actually, I'm now wondering if it's because the first 10 options (the popular options) exist twice in the list.

Comment: It turns out that having two options with the same value is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code ::

Make it scroll to top using this code :

```
$('select').scrollTop(0);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0ftL6w3y/3/)

Comment: That worked but I ended up just adding a leading zero to the "popular" items so that all options had a unique value.  The value is used as an `int` on the backend so the leading zero makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have your HTML codes and other styles including your page content placement. Here, I have tried to achieve what you want in the following.

Check this demo.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.select-menu {border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;height: 90px;margin: 10px;padding: 10px;width: 90px;}
.select-menu > select {width: 85px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="select-menu">
<select size="5">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```